# TypeError: ws_connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_msg_size' randomly started showing up anytime I run

Tags: python, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

testbot.py", line 16, in <module> client.run(token)

client.py", line 718, in run return future.result()

client.py", line 697, in runner await self.start(*args, kwargs)

client.py", line 661, in start await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)

client.py", line 558, in connect self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)

tasks.py", line 494, in wait_for return fut.result()

gateway.py", line 306, in from_client socket = await client.http.ws_connect(gateway)

http.py", line 132, in ws_connect return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, kwargs)

TypeError: ws_connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_msg_size'
```

I get these errors any time I run my bot. I tried making a new python doc and writing a simple hello command to see if any code I was running was causing it to be unable to start, but even the most simple code is causing this.

```
###testbot###
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'a token'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Entering {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def testcmd(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Test')

client.run(token)
```

I think it has something to do with either my discord.py or discord itself, but I want to see what you guys think before I take any measures.
Note: My token doesn't say A token there in my actual bot.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out for myself if anyone else gets this ever.

1. uninstall discord.py
2. update pip
3. reinstall discord.py